# How to get correct syntax highlighting for ejs files on VS Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, editor, ejs

I am trying to put the **ejs** template in my HTML, but it will not highlight the syntax at all.
I have the **EJS** language support extension installed, and I even went into my user setting to put the following:

```
"files.associations": {
    ".ejs": "html"
}
```

But it still did not work.

UPDATE: The issue was with my version of VSCode. I needed to update VSCode to the newest version in order to get it to work

Comment: "files.associations": {".ejs": "html"} try  .ejs to  *.ejs

Comment: @gowthamrajan I've tried that and it still doesn't work